# What is the thing used to help pouring liquids called?

Tags: word-request

I'm referring to the highlighted part of the measuring cup below:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_a_Little_Teapot

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Spout or pouring lip

> spout
>   NOUN
>   1A tube or lip projecting from a container, through which liquid can be poured.
>
> ‘a teapot with a chipped spout’

[Spout](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spout)

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a spout without a cover, but it's certainly the thing's lip.

Comment: Spouts don't have to have covers.

Answer (score 13):

It's called a *spout*, cf. this [Double spout measuring cup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0096DLLM8) on Amazon.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spout) defines it as:

> 1 : a pipe or conductor through which a liquid is discharged or conveyed in a stream: such as
>   ...
>   b : a projecting tube or lip from which a liquid (such as water) issues